# hadoop failed to build from source

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to build hadoop-2.0.4-alpha from source..in ubuntu 13.04
I have maven 3.0.5, protobuf(libprotoc 2.4.1), cmake(2.8.10.1)

i get this

```
 occured: stylesheet /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/${env.FINDBUGS_HOME}/src/xsl/default.xsl doesn't exist. -> [Help 1]

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (site) on project hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: stylesheet /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/${env.FINDBUGS_HOME}/src/xsl/default.xsl doesn't exist.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: stylesheet /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/${env.FINDBUGS_HOME}/src/xsl/default.xsl doesn't exist.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml:44: stylesheet /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.0.4-alpha-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/${env.FINDBUGS_HOME}/src/xsl/default.xsl doesn't exist.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.handleError(XSLTProcess.java:1229)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.execute(XSLTProcess.java:380)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:270)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

Comment: I got the same error on hadoop-2.0.5-alpha from source in ubuntu 12.04. Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved by following commands:

```
 mvn clean
 mvn compile -Pnative
 mvn package
 mvn compile findbugs:findbugs
 mvn install
 mvn package -Pdist,docs,src,native -Dtar
```

Comment: You should see the problem is pah for FINDBUGS_HOME was not set after setting that it would work fine as per hadoop installation steps

Answer (score 6):

I think your environment is missing FINDBUGS_HOME. You can download and install findbugs from [here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html).

After that, you should run following to define FINDBUGS_HOME:

```
export FINDBUGS_HOME=/path/to/findbugs/installation
```

Now, your build should not fail due to missing FINDBUGS_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue using these steps.

1) open the pom.xml file inside the hadoop-xxxxx-src/hadoop-project directory and search for the "findbugs.version" xml tag

2) download and install the required findbugs version you found in Step 1)

3) create the "FINDBUGS_HOME" environment variable as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

For an updated answer, my colleague published an article on how to compile, patch and run hadoop with the latest source code: https://www.adaltas.com/en/2020/08/04/installing-hadoop-from-source/. It makes use of Docker for reproducible builds.